# function isn't printing out 1 through 10 in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created a function a function that I want to pass in 2 parameters, and whetever numbers I pass into those parameters, I want the function to store not only those 2 numbers, but everything in between them into an array. Here's my code below:

```
    a = [];

var range = function(start, end) {
  for (j=start;j<=end;j++) {
  return a.push(j);
  return a;
  }
}

console.log(range(5, 20));
```

In this case, I want it to store the numbers 5 - 20 into my array (a) so I can later get the sum via another function.

**My code above isn't working. What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: You don't want a `return` in front of `a.push(j)`, and your `return a` should be outside your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` keyword aborts the function immediately. Move it outside the `for` loop to get the desired result.

```js
var a = [];

var range = function(start, end) {
  for (j = start; j <= end; j++) {
    a.push(j);
  }
  return a;
}

console.log(range(5, 20));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the return after you complete the loop.

```
var range = function(start, end) {
  a = [];
  for (j=start;j<=end;j++) {
    a.push(j);
  }
  return a;
}

console.log(range(5, 20));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue, as others have pointed out, is that you are returning from your function after the first loop iteration. You are also returning `a.push()` which returns the length of the array, not the actual array.

An even better solution, though would be to not use a global variable, and simply leverage the built in Array prototype methods like so:

You can use `Array(end-start + 1)` to create an array with the number of elements you need. Then you can use `Array.apply().map()` to map into the numbers in the array, starting at `start` and incrementing by the index of the array element.

```js
var range = function(start, end) {
  return Array.apply(null, Array(end - start + 1)).map((elem, index) => start + index);
}

console.log(range(5, 20));
```

Comment: is the .apply method a built in Array method? just curious

Comment: @MarketHydra Well, `Array` is the constructor *function* to create a new array, and `.apply()` is a built in method on the Function prototype. [Here are the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)